# Ignoring unnecessary parts of URLs inside Nginx location tag

Tags: nginx

Consider the following Nginx configuration file (Nginx version 1.2.6 on 64-bit Linux):

```
location / {
    root html/www.domain.com;
}
location /image/ {
    root html/static.domain.com;
}
```

Using this configuration, `/index.html` is picked up from `html/www.domain.com/index.html`; `/secure/profile.html` is picked up from `html/www.domain.com/secure/profile.html` and `/image/logo.jpeg` is picked up from `html/static.domain.com/image/logo.jpeg`.

However, requests to the following result in errors (understandably):

```
/index.html;affiliate=msn
/image/logo.jpef~partner=msnbc
```

What should be the correct Nginx configuration to ignore URL parts such as `;affiliate=msn` and `~partner=msnbc`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this

```
    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/index.html =404;
    }
    location ~ "(.*)[;~].*" {
        try_files $1 $1/index.html =404;
    }
```

Comment: Although we had solved the problem before your answer, I really appreciate your taking out the time to answer the question.  I am accepting your answer as it is indeed a valid solution to the problem we were facing.  The only thing would be to escape the semi-colon as [\;\~].  Without escaping it our Nginx installation would find the configuration file invalid.

Answer (score 0):

Have changed the configuration as follows to get the desired behaviour.

```
location /image/ {
    rewrite ^(/image/.*)[\;\,\~].*$ $1 break;
    root    html/static.domain.com;
}
```

Please note that semi-colon has to be escaped (\;) since it is a statement delimiter in Nginx configuration files.